# Algolia return results only when search is done

Tags: reactjs, next.js, algolia

I have set up algolia and for some reason, it populates search results by default some weird behavior that I don't need for my use case. For context, this behavior is seen at a firebase semi-live [link](https://youtu.be/ZNVAPpTpKpk?t=2285) where results just auto-populate with no search having been done. How can I disable this, and only return results when a search (keystroke) is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this what you are looking for
The React Instantsearch docs give an example on how to [Handle empty queries](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/conditional-display/react/#handling-empty-queries) using the [`connectStateResults`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/state-results/react/#connector) connector to create a custom component. It gives access to the `searchState` of the application.

for example you can create a custom hits component to show hits only when there is a query. Similarly can create a modified pagination component.

```js
const ModifiedHits = connectStateResults(({ searchState }) =>
  searchState && searchState.query ? (
      <Hits hitComponent={Hit} />
  ) : (
    <div>Empty search</div>
  )
);
```

after that use the component as `<ModifiedHits />`

[image: Edit React InstantSearch - connectStateResults empty query]